# When is a Java object fully initialized?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

As one may know, an object just allocated by the `new` bytecode is not initialized, and is thus not a `java.lang.Object`. If I do runtime bytecode manipulation and give that object to a method, the JVM will complain or even crash (because the "thing" I gave it is not a `java.lang.Object`).

So, my question is, when are objects "fully" initialized, i.e. become a `java.lang.Object`? Is that when the constructor (`<init>`):

- is called?
- returns?
- some time before it returns?
- calls `java.lang.Object.<init>`?
- some other timing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the perspective of any given `<init>` method, the `this` value is considered initialized after the call to `invokespecial` returns, whether that is calling another `<init>` method in the same class or a superclass.

Likewise, for objects created with the `new` instruction, they are considered initialized once you `invokespecial` an `<init>` method on them.

Note that initialization tracking is local to a method. Bytecode verification is done on a method by method basis and each method only sees the objects that are created within it and the calls to  methods. The fact that it is impossible to initialize the this value in a constructor without calling another constructor ensures that it will eventually chain up to a `java.lang.Object` constructor unless it throws or goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Very reasonable argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bytecode of  method of a "Foo" class

```
 public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LFooTest; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

when you try to create a new instance of Foo,  will INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object. ()V, and after that, the object will be created in heap memory and the reference in stack will be return and assigned to "this". so, in my opinion, the answer of your question should be "after calling java.lang.Object.init()”

Comment: Actually, the object exists in the heap before you even invoke the constructor. Otherwise, there would be no `this` value to pass to it.